# RTK mutation POST with an array iteration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rtk-query

I have two table set up one for a people and another for drinks consumed. This means that i have a pivot table and i need to post an array of drinks consumed in my rtk query. How do i go about this?

So for example my data will be:

```
firstname = "Joe",
secondname= "blogs",
drinks_consumed = [1, 3, 4]
```

I need to iterate through this and pass it into my trigger function, I have tried to hard code this but couldn't get it to work? Can this be achieved with RTK?

```
const [addNewDrinker, { isSuccess }] = useAddNewDrinkerMutation()
    
const onSaveDrinkerClicked = async () => {
     
try {
await addNewDrinker({ firstname, secondname, drinks_consumed: 1, drinks_consumed: 2(i would prefer to iterate though this array if possible) }).unwrap()
            
} catch (err) {
console.error('Failed to save the Drinker: ', err)
}
}
```

currently getting an error in the trigger function, presumably on the drinks_consumed.

```
   createDrinker: builder.mutation({
      query: drinkerData => ({
        url: '/drinker/create',
        method: 'POST',
        // Include the entire post object as the body of the request
        body: drinkerData,

      }),


    }),
```

Comment: Please share how exactly the data you have looks like, what your endpoint definition looks like and what exact data you want to send to your backend.

Comment: The data i want to send has been posted under 'for example my data' will be. My endpoint is just a standard basic 'POST mutation. I will add it now though

Comment: But why don't you just do `drinks_consumed: [ 1, 3, 4 ]` then? You seem to not be communicating something, because with the information you are giving right now it's not really clear what you are asking for or what piece of the puzzle is missing for you. If you already have that data you can just pass it in, right?

Comment: Because that was originally bringing back an error for me. Now it seems to be working. :D. Thank you for the help anyway